# Palavra com maior frequência em uma string a partir de um tamanho

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver um problema, onde eu preciso ver a palavra com maior frequência em uma String.
O problema é que essas palavras são montadas a partir de um tamanho dado.
Por exemplo:

```
"5tardenoitemanhãtardenoitetarde"
```

Eu precisaria pegar o primeiro número, que é o tamanho das palavras que preciso procurar na String que vem depois desse número, e devolver a palavra com maior frequência.

```
tarde
noite
manhã
tarde
noite
tarde
```

Nesse caso seria a palavra "tarde".

Alguém teria ideia de como poderia fazer, da forma mais "limpa" possível, além de ter uma verificação caso não haja palavras repetidas?

Comment: O que já testaste?

Comment: É o trivial, não tem muito o que fazer, ou itere pela lista de palavras buscando correspondências ou use expressões regulares.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não é assim tão trivial :)

Comment: @Sergio trivial que digo é não dá para abreviar o código usando algorítimos que gerem atalhos em problemas similares com por exemplo distancia lichtenstein para avaliar similaridades entre strings.

Comment: @AugustoVasques vou dar uma resposta, pensei que desse para usar uma regex tipo `/(\d+)(\D{\1})+` mas o grupo de captura não apanha o que procurava. Se tiveres outra ideia de resposta mais simples coloca também!

Comment: @Sergio estou acabando de escrever uma resposta, mas não vai sair muito diferente do que fez.

Answer (score 2):

Isso precisa de vários passos...

Deixo uma sugestão. Basicamente:

- separa a parte numérica do resto
- interpreta o valor do numero
- cria uma regex para apanhar o comprimento esperado
- cria um objeto com um contador
- usa um reduce para saber qual a palavra mais usada...

```js
const string = "5tardenoitemanhãtardenoitetarde";
const numericPart = string.match(/\d+/)[0];
const rest = string.slice(numericPart.length);
const nrs = Number(numericPart);
const regex = new RegExp(`\\D{${nrs}}`, 'g');
const words = rest.match(regex);
const count = words.reduce((obj, word) => {
  if (!obj[word]) obj[word] = 0;
  obj[word]++;
  return obj;
}, {});

const max = Object.keys(count).reduce((mostCommonWord, word) => {
  if (!mostCommonWord) return word;
  return (count[mostCommonWord] < count[word]) ? word : mostCommonWord;
}, null);

console.log('Mais usada:', max);
console.log('Todas:', count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas obtive a quantidade de letras por palavra usando a [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `^\d+` que busca um ou mais dígitos que iniciem a frase e então removi os dígitos da entrada com [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Criei uma expressão regular baseada no tamanho anteriormente obtido e então a usei para fraturar a entrada em palavras de tamanho fixo.

Então foi só catalogar e contar as palavras e depois verificar qual apareceu mais.

```js
let str = "5tardenoitemanhãtardenoitetarde";

let tamanho = str.match(/^\d+/).join();       //Obtem a quantidade de letras
str = str.slice(tamanho.length);              //Remove a parte numérica
let reg = new RegExp(`.{1,${tamanho}}`, "g");
let palavras = str.match(reg);                //Quebra a string em palavras do mesmo tamanho

let resultados = {};

//Conta a ocorrencia de cada palavra
palavras.map((palavra) => {
  if (resultados[palavra] == null) resultados[palavra] = 0; //Se a palavra ainda não foi catalogada inicializa seu contador
  resultados[palavra] = resultados[palavra] + 1;            //A cada ocorrência incrementa o contador da palavra 
});

let maximo = {
  palavra: "",
  ocorrencias: 0
};

//Obtém a palavra que mais se repetiu.
Object.entries(resultados).forEach((palavra) => {
  if (palavra[1] > maximo.ocorrencias) maximo = {
    palavra: palavra[0],
    ocorrencias: palavra[1]
  };
});

console.log("============ ocorrências ============");
console.log(resultados);
console.log("========= maior ocorrência ==========");
console.log(maximo);
```